# Создание прокручиваемого списка DIV-ов динамически

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.
Пытаюсь сформировать динамический список с прокруткой.
Вот HTML-часть:

```
<div id="autocom" style="font-size: 24 px; position: absolute; float: left;" class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Остановка: </label>
        <input id="tags" type="text"/>
        <div id="bus_stop" style="position: relative; font-size: 24 px;"></div>
 </div>
 <div style="overflow: auto; float: left; position: relative; height: fit-content;" id="routes">            
 </div>
```

В JS устанавливаю автозаполнение для DIV-а с тегом autocom (код приводить не буду, т.к. он отношения к делу не имеет). Так вот, после выбора элемента из списка автозаполнения у меня отрабатывает следующая функция:

```
function hideshow() {
            if (label) {
                var routes = document.getElementById('routes');
                routes.style.display == '';
                var Buses = ["29", "2", "3", "4", "7", "10", "22"];
                var div = "<div style=\"margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;\">";
                var $div = "</div>";
                var hr = "<hr>";
                Buses.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
                    routes.innerHTML = hr + div + "Маршрут №" + item.toString() + " : " + "14:50" + hr + $div;
                });
            }
```

Собственно, я просто хочу, чтобы у меня динамически созданные div-ы расположились друг под другом. А получается вот что:
[image: скрин]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В цикле с начала сформируйте контент, а потом уже делайте вставку в html.

```
var html = '';
Buses.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    html += hr + div + "Маршрут №" + item.toString() + " : " + "14:50" + hr + $div;
});
routes.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.